# PHP to set the value of a check box to the same as that chosen in a drop down list

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I am trying to set the value of a check box to the same as what has been chosen by the use in a drop down list:

If option A is selected in a drop down list I want the check box value to be A
If option B is selected in a drop down list I want the check box value to be B

```
HTML

Car type:
<select name="CarType">
<option value="select...">Select....</option>
<option value="Ford">Ford</option>
<option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>

<input type="hidden" name="SelectedCarValue" value="No" />
Are you buying the car:<input type="checkbox" name="buying" value=<?php $_GET["CarType"]; ?>>
```

I am then submitting the form to output the values of this.

Thanks

Comment: If you want this to change when the user selects something from the menu, you have to do it in Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: can i use Jquery for this?

Comment: Yes, very easily. Give it a try and come back with a question if you have trouble.